# powershell select-string output to file

Tags: powershell

I'm using powershell to locate an email address in a htm file and write it out to a text file.
I'm using select-string which finds the string OK, but writes the line number as well as the email address to the file.

All I want is the email address!  It seems simple enough, but I can't crack it.

Here's my code:

```
$List_htm = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.htm

# Loop:
foreach ($htm in $List_htm)
{
    # Locate recipient email address to send to:
    # Regex pattern to match:
    $pattern = '(^\W*.*@.*\.{1,}\w*$)'

    $sel = select-string -list $htm -pattern $pattern | Select-Object Line
    If ($Sel -eq $null)
{
    write-host "FAILS - $htm does NOT contain $pattern"
}
Else 
{
    write-host "WORKS! $pattern `n$sel"
} 

Write-host "end"

    $EmailAddressee = $PDFFolder + "EmailAddressee.txt"
    $sel | Out-File $EmailAddressee
}
```

However emailaddressee.txt looks like this:

```
Line                                                                                                                                                                    
----                                                                                                                                                                    
                fred.bloggs@helpmeplease.com
```

All I want is a single line with the email address in:

```
fred.bloggs@helpmeplease.com
```

I could obviously further process this results  file in powershell to get this, but I'm hoping someone can come up with a simple one stage result.

Thanks

Ian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the following line:

```
$sel = select-string -list $htm -pattern $pattern | Select-Object Line
```

To:

```
$sel = select-string -list $htm -pattern $pattern | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line
```

That will ensure you write the property of the object rather than the textual representation of the object itself

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks arco444. Works a treat.  I've also added
`$sel = $sel.trim()` 
to remove the leading spaces and just leave the email address. I don't have enough reputation points yet to upvote you, but thanks anyway.